# How use Java with google maps api?

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3

## Java with Google maps api

---

I'd like to begin a project with Java that needs a map. I've been thinking about either Google Maps or another Open Source map. How would I implement this?

Comment: Read the manual, then identify API-Functions you want to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, I would offer you to use google maps api, they are using REST services and they are very good.

Here is a short explantation:
You need to make an HTTP request with a URL with the parameters you wish (such as the location - longtitude, latitude, the address, and more), this code should be made in java. If you did everything correct, you will recieve a response of type (xaml or json, depends on the URL you sent, it is preferable to use JSON).

After you receive the response you need to deserialize it, which seems to be hard, but is very simple, for example JSON has many ways and built in methods to do it.

And then you can do whatever you wish with the objects you received.

So here are some links:

Google API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=iw&csw=1

JSON Deserialize - http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm or a better one (if you want to make many requests) - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

- [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en)
- [The Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en)
- [The Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?hl=en)

Comment: for a Java API, https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java  this OSS API is community supported and advertised on the Google Maps official site. Incidentally, this is yet another very useful question that some SO dictadministrator is closing out of purely ideological views: "too broad": please define which metrics and thresholds you use to measure "broadness" and "too"